# How do I edit a title to avoid adding another question?

Tags: support, posting

I just found a solution to a problem (in Python, by myself), and answered my own question. I later enhanced my code into something "better" and possibly useful for a new "future technology", and then ran into another problem in coding.

Then, I deleted the answer to my previous question, and edited it into a second question (replacing my previous question), but the title of the problem doesn't match now, and when I try to edit the title of my question, I can't.

How can I easily edit the title of my question, without having to create another question?

Comment: There should't be any problems in editing the title, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120417/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-question-title-once-asked. However, you shouldn't edit your question to one completely different question anyway, as answers and comments might not make any sense anymore when you change the question.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to edit the title? Does the system block you, and if so, what's the message? Also, if there are already other answers to the question, don't change it, since you're guaranteed to invalidate them. It would also help if you actually linked to the question, and explained what changes you would like to make, as it's currently not very clear. Please add all the relevant information into this question.

Comment: You can not use a title that is ***identical*** to the title of an existing question. This may or may not indicate you have used a short generic ***unspecific*** title (I haven't looked at your questions yet).